# I don't think people are getting the edit thing.

Tags: discussion, editing

Here's an example of where I start to read a question, then get to the end and the person adds a bunch of edits that just end up confusing me instead of fixing the original question:

- [Handle Doc/Docx Templates on a headless server to produce PDFs preferably without using OpenOffice.org](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24096/convert-docx-or-odt-to-pdf)

This is just one I've seen today, on top of that people tack

**UPDATE!!!!11** It works!

**UPDATE2** Wait, no it doesn't

**UPDATE3** It works again!

How can we encourage people to edit their question to just read right on the first read? I don't understand why people use the "Update" or "Edit" thing either, the dropdown thing notifies me when someone updates a question or answer.

Thoughts on how to improve this? (Yes I know it's mostly new user education, I'd just like to see how we can collectively explain this better to people).

Comment: Ah, I've done the "update" thing myself.  I had seen it so often, I thought it was the way to go. Ha.
 We need something like a meta post to show up on the sidebar that has an askubuntu version of 'writing the perfect question' (and we can change "the perfect question" to "an understandable question").

Comment: Right, that's why I want to bring it up now so we can do the right thing earlier before we get too big to adapt.

Comment: The dropdown thing only notifies those who have favorite'd the question right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is tricky -- we do want to encourage people to **edit** their questions (or answers) when updating them rather than posting new ones, of course.

So two guidelines: if the updates are small and one-off, I think the pattern of

> Content
>
> **One-off edit:**
>   Change to my content

Isn't great but it is OK. When you have a LOT of updates, I think that falls apart and you should switch to:

> Content
>
> I tried this, and this happened in detail.
>
> I tried this, and this happened in detail.
>
> I tried this, and this happened in detail.

Essentially you are *telling a story*, the story of what happened when you tried to solve problem X. So it should be written to read like a story, with proper paragraphs and a narrative arc.

Comment: +1 for the story-telling analogy. I like to fully describe the initial problem and then follow up with fix-attempts and their effects. That also helps those who already answered to figure out what's new, which would otherwise be hard to see without looking at the revision history.